# I have a space between 2 images on 100% width

Tags: html, css

So, I'm designing a login page. I'm currently stuck on a really annoying issue. So, I have 2 divs, that are supposed to be next to each other, splitting the page exactly in half. But, Instead of being right next to each other, they are separated by a large chunk of nothing.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#rightSide {
  background-image: url('/rightSide.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#OrgaChat {
  display: inline-block;
}

#signInForm {
  display: inline-block;
}

#leftSide {
  background-image: url('/leftSide.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>OrgaChat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='leftSide'></div>
  <div id='rightSide'>
    <h1 id='OrgaChat'>OrgaChat</h1>
    <div id='loginBox'>
      <form class="signInForm">
        <div class="SignInDiv"><input type="text" placeholder='Email' class='signInInput'></div>
        <div class="SignInDiv"><input type="text" placeholder='Password' class="signInInput"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="loginFormSubmit">Log In!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is the HTML/CSS Code. When I run it, I get this:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Goto https://placeholder.com and get some images for the snippet

Comment: How big are the images? You have them set to `no-repeat`, so it might not be that there is any space, just that the images don't stretch far enough.

Answer (score 2):

add `background-size:100% 100%;` or `background-size:cover` in `#rightSide` and `#leftSide`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Your images likely aren't stretching far enough, giving an impression of white-space. Try adding `background-size: cover`:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#rightSide {
  background-image: url('https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/abstract-green-background-picture-id689323732?k=6&m=689323732&s=612x612&w=0&h=EJlWrflccYuhV74Z3O-eXvTAo0sfMH7SZhO_-xWNMDg=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#OrgaChat {
  display: inline-block;
}

#signInForm {
  display: inline-block;
}

#leftSide {
  background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bb/4c/c3/bb4cc3b2fae7978db32f35b4519cc0f8.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>OrgaChat</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id='leftSide'></div>
  <div id='rightSide'>
    <h1 id='OrgaChat'>OrgaChat</h1>
    <div id='loginBox'>
      <form class="signInForm">
        <div class="SignInDiv"><input type="text" placeholder='Email' class='signInInput'></div>
        <div class="SignInDiv"><input type="text" placeholder='Password' class="signInInput"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="loginFormSubmit">Log In!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove the default margin of leftSide and rightSide DIV and check

```css
#rightSide {
  background-image: url('/rightSide.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin:0px;
}
#leftSide {
  background-image: url('/leftSide.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin:0px;
}
```